# iOS Plain Table classify rows accordingly to date programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, dynamic, classification

I need some help with tables and have studied many examples/tutorials similar to http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/

However, I could not find information that is applicable for my context and decided to seek some help here! :)

What I already did:

- Arrange rows(containing book details) accordingly to due dates
- Create section headers containing the due dates

What I need to do:

- Classify the rows accordingly to the due dates
- If due dates is similar, row would be under the same section header

Thanks all! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary where the key for each entry in a due date and the value for the entry is an array of book details.  The number of sections is the number of dates, the number of rows for each section is the count of the array that matches the date for that section.

Comment: Thanks I think I get what you mean! But where should I create the dictionary? Before the returning of rows and sections is it? Sorry cause I'm new to xcode, especially tables. Thanks ^^

Comment: I think you should create it wherever you currently arrange your book details.  It can be a property of the view controller that handles your table (assuming you don't need the book information in any other controller).

Comment: I've tried creating a dictionary with due date as keys. However, when there is a same key(due date), the second similar key with different entry value would not be shown.

Comment: I've tried on some sample codes first and I tried to insert same keys with different values: NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrTemp1,@"A",arrTemp2,@"A",arrTemp3,@"C",nil]; but what happens is that object in arrTemp2 was not displayed.

Comment: You're missing the part where the value/object should be an array.   For key @"A" your object should be one array that contains temp1 and temp2.

Comment: thanks for your help so far. Will continue on with some experimenting! Thanks so much! :D Have a nice day!